# How can i create multiple junction record in apex

Tags: apex

My requirement is , lets say i have 5 opportunity ids and one promotion id . And i want to make 5 opportunityPromotion Records. for the first opportunity record its happening but when looping through next record it gives error,but getting error

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a3R7j000001Dv3hEAC;
> first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an
> insert call: [Id].

But I want to make 5 opportunityPromotion records with 5 opportunity and one promotion records.

```
Promotion__c Promotion=[select id,Quantity__c,name from Promotion__c where id=:recordid];
    system.debug('Promotion check '+Promotion);
    list<Opportunity_Promotion__c> OppPromotionList =new list<Opportunity_Promotion__c>();
    for (String op :OppIdList){
        Opportunity_Promotion__c oppPromotion= new Opportunity_Promotion__c();
        oppPromotion.Blood_Drive_Opportunity__c=op;
        oppPromotion.Promotion__c=Promotion.Id;
        //oppPromotion.Quantity__c=Promotion.Quantity__c;
        OppPromotionList.add(oppPromotion);
        if(!OppPromotionList.isEmpty()){
            Database.insert(OppPromotionList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to take the insert outside of the for loop

Comment: To avoid this common problem, see [Bulk Apex Triggers Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) or search the for "bulkify Apex" for best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Promotion__c Promotion=[select id,Quantity__c,name from Promotion__c where id=:recordid];

    list<Opportunity_Promotion__c> OppPromotionList =new list<Opportunity_Promotion__c>();
    for (String op :OppIdList){
        Opportunity_Promotion__c oppPromotion= new Opportunity_Promotion__c();
        oppPromotion.Blood_Drive_Opportunity__c=op;
        oppPromotion.Promotion__c=Promotion.Id;
        //oppPromotion.Quantity__c=Promotion.Quantity__c;
        OppPromotionList.add(oppPromotion);
        
    }
    Database.insert(OppPromotionList);
```

Remove the `Database.insert` from the for loop; No need to check for empty list as no DML is burned on empty collections